# android studio value check box, only checked send from message

Tags: android, checkbox

I'm new to android studio and trying to send a value checkbox that only checked via SMS message.

I change the value to `String` so all value checkbox sent though it's unchecked

Please, help me fixing the program so that the value checkbox only checked are sent via `SMS` message.

Full code:

```
private EditText qty1, qty2,qty3,qty4,qty5,qty6;
private CheckBox cos5,cos10,cos20,cos25,cos50,cos100;
private Spinner spinnerrs;
private Button buttonsendtrx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trx);

    qty1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextQty1);
    qty2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextQty2);
    qty3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextQty3);
    qty4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextQty4);
    qty5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextQty5);
    qty6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextQty6);
    cos5 =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.S05);
    cos10=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.S10);
    cos20=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.S20);
    cos25=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.S25);
    cos50=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.S50);
    cos100=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.S100);

    buttonsendtrx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsendtrx);
    addItemOnSpinner();

     buttonsendtrx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;

            if (view==buttonsendtrx);
             {
                 sendsms();
             }
         }
     });
    }


public void sendsms () {

    Log.i("Send SMS","");
    String nomor = spinnerrs.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String jumlah1 = qty1.getText().toString();
    String jumlah2 = qty2.getText().toString();
    String jumlah3 = qty3.getText().toString();
    String jumlah4 = qty4.getText().toString();
    String jumlah5 = qty5.getText().toString();
    String jumlah6 = qty6.getText().toString();
    String s5 = cos5.getText().toString();
    String s10 = cos10.getText().toString();
    String s20 = cos20.getText().toString();
    String s25 = cos25.getText().toString();
    String s50 = cos50.getText().toString();
    String s100 = cos100.getText().toString();


    {
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(nomor, null, s5+jumlah1+s10+jumlah2+s20+jumlah3+s25+jumlah4+s50+jumlah5+s100++jumlah6, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS SEND", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS FAILED,PLEASE TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public void addItemOnSpinner() {
    spinnerrs = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerrs);
    List<String> kategori = new ArrayList<String>();
    kategori.add("08127648200");
    kategori.add("081276482000");
    kategori.add("081275250000");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,kategori);
    dataadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerrs.setAdapter(dataadapter);
}
```

public void selectItem(View view)
    {

```
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.S05:

        if (checked){
            qty1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            qty1.setFocusable(true);
            qty1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            qty1.setCursorVisible(true);
            qty1.setEnabled(true);
            qty1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
        else {
            //selection.remove(String.valueOf(cos5));
            qty1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
            //qty1.setTextIsSelectable(false);
            qty1.setFocusable(false);
            qty1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            qty1.setCursorVisible(false);
            qty1.setEnabled(false);
            qty1.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            break;
        }

        case R.id.S10:
            if (checked){
                qty2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                qty2.setFocusable(true);
                qty2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                qty2.setCursorVisible(true);
                qty2.setEnabled(true);
                qty2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                break;
            }
            else {
                qty2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));

                qty2.setFocusable(false);
                qty2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                qty2.setCursorVisible(false);
                qty2.setEnabled(false);
                qty2.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            }

        case R.id.S20:
            if (checked){
                qty3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                qty3.setFocusable(true);
                qty3.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                qty3.setCursorVisible(true);
                qty3.setEnabled(true);
                qty3.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                break;
            }
            else {
                qty3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));

                qty3.setFocusable(false);
                qty3.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                qty3.setCursorVisible(false);
                qty3.setEnabled(false);
                qty3.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            }

        case R.id.S25:
            if (checked){
                qty4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                qty4.setFocusable(true);
                qty4.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                qty4.setCursorVisible(true);
                qty4.setEnabled(true);
                qty4.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                break;
            }
            else {
                qty4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
                //qty4.setTextIsSelectable(false);
                qty4.setFocusable(false);
                qty4.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                qty4.setCursorVisible(false);
                qty4.setEnabled(false);
                qty4.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.S50:
            if (checked){
                qty5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                //qty5.setTextIsSelectable(true);
                qty5.setFocusable(true);
                qty5.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                qty5.setCursorVisible(true);
                qty5.setEnabled(true);
                qty5.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            else {
                qty5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
                qty5.setFocusable(false);
                qty5.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                qty5.setCursorVisible(false);
                qty5.setEnabled(false);
                qty5.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            }
        case R.id.S100:
            if (checked){
                qty6.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                qty6.setFocusable(true);
                qty6.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                qty6.setCursorVisible(true);
                qty6.setEnabled(true);
                qty6.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            else {
                qty6.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
                qty6.setFocusable(false);
                qty6.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                qty6.setCursorVisible(false);
                qty6.setEnabled(false);
                qty6.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: what is your exact question?

Comment: please... how to fix the program so that the value checkbox only checked are sent via sms message.  thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendsms () {

Log.i("Send SMS","");
String nomor = spinnerrs.getSelectedItem().toString();
String jumlah1 = qty1.getText().toString();
String jumlah2 = qty2.getText().toString();
String jumlah3 = qty3.getText().toString();
String jumlah4 = qty4.getText().toString();
String jumlah5 = qty5.getText().toString();
String jumlah6 = qty6.getText().toString();

if(cos5.isChecked){
String s5 = cos5.getText().toString();
return;
}
if(cos10.isChecked){
String s10 = cos10.getText().toString();
return;
}
if(cos20.isChecked){
String s20 = cos20.getText().toString();
return;
}
if(cos25.isChecked){
String s25 = cos25.getText().toString();
return;
}
if(cos50.isChecked){
String s50 = cos50.getText().toString();
return;
}
if(cos100.isChecked){
String s100 = cos100.getText().toString();
return;
}


try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        smsManager.sendTextMessage(nomor, null, s5+jumlah1+s10+jumlah2+s20+jumlah3+s25+jumlah4+s50+jumlah5+s100++jumlah6, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS SEND", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS FAILED,PLEASE TRY AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: W4R10CK. I have try this. but It's say cannot resolve symbol 'isChecked'. what should i do? thanks

Comment: have resolve symbol 'isChecked'. but still error in s5,s10,s20,s25,s50,s100 in sms manager. its red. error cannot resolve s5,

Comment: in  here : smsManager.sendTextMessage(nomor, null, s5+jumlah1+s10+jumlah2+s20+jumlah3+s25+jumlah4+s50+jumlah5+s100++jumlah6, null, null);    //still not solved

Comment: yes, try defining the s5,s10... string outside the if condition. Like `String s5; String s10` and inside if use `s5 = cos5.getText().toString();` so on.

Comment: please help me.. it's have 3 week can't solve this. thanx

Comment: i try to type String s5 and else outside condition. it's error when i run the project error unfortunately, android stopped.

Comment: firstnameprashant@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

First Find if the checkbox is checked or not, and add it to a string as follows:-

```
 String msg_to_send="";
    if(cos5.isChecked()){
    msg_to_send = msg_to_send+cos5.getText().toString();
    }
    if(cos10.isChecked()){
    msg_to_send = msg_to_send+cos10.getText().toString();
    }
    if(cos20.isChecked()){
    msg_to_send = msg_to_send+ cos20.getText().toString();
    }
    if(cos25.isChecked()){
    msg_to_send = msg_to_send+cos25.getText().toString();
    }
    if(cos50.isChecked()){
   msg_to_send = msg_to_send+ cos50.getText().toString();
    }
    if(cos100.isChecked()){
   msg_to_send = msg_to_send+cos100.getText().toString();

    }
```

Send this string to your sms:-

```
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(nomor, null, msg_to_send, null, null);//you can add your editText also
```

Comment: it's doesn't work either. error when running it. unfortunately android stopped

Comment: what exception you are getting